# Why does git for windows push for over an hour?

Tags: git, tfs

I have had some issues where for some reason a git push deleted most of my files from the /packages and have since recovered them but now when I tried to push I left it for over an hour and it's still using like 40mbps of upload.

I'm working on a asp.net mvc app and I am early in the development so it's mostly the usual files.

Should I skip pushing for now and leave it for an overnight push? Can I somehow postpone these files for a later push?

```
Counting objects: 105, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (52/52), done.
Writing objects: 100% (64/64), 118.51 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 64 (delta 32), reused 2 (delta 0)
```

Comment: There is obviously a problem, you should try to find it and fix it, not just leave it for an overnight jobby... assuming it will ever even finish

Comment: I can't come up with anything better than just leaving it to upload. I have managed to get to an ealrier commit before the delete on another branch and have checked it out but will have to make a ruling on this one eventually.

Comment: You should not be putting the /packages/ folder from NuGet in source control in the first place. Binaries should never be put into Git repos as Git cannot effectively version them, so the repo becomes bloated over time. Rely on NuGet package restore to download the appropriate binaries as necessary.